# In Perl how can I save a hash that contains subroutine references?

Tags: perl, serialization, hashmap

As the title says, in Perl, how can I save a hash that contains a list of subroutine references? For example, I have the following hash that contains the references to the subroutines which are contained in other libraries:

```
my %testMap = (
  helloTest        => \&runHello,
  goodbyeTest      => \&runGoodbye,
);
```

When I try to use [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.131/Dumper.pm) in the following matter:

```
my($out) = new FileHandle ">$fileName"; 
my $serialized => Data::Dumper->Dump([\%testMap], [$HASH_REFERENCE]); 
print $out $serialized; 
close $out;
```

I end up with a file that looks like the following:

```
$testMap = {
             'goodbyeTest' => sub { "DUMMY" },
             'helloTest' => sub { "DUMMY" }
           };
```

When I would like the output to look like what appears in the original listing, is there a way to do this?

Some experimentation with Data::Dumper and [Storable](http://search.cpan.org/~ams/Storable-2.39/Storable.pm) have so far turned up nothing and I suspect that it is due to the actual code for the references not being available to the code that is running.

Comment: Define "the original listing"?

Comment: @TLP - The very first code listing in the question.

Comment: @choroba - It's part of a testing framework, the runner expects to get a hash map tests to run and for various reasons this hash can be modified in such a way that persisting it to disk is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Storable`](https://metacpan.org/module/Storable#CODE-REFERENCES) has been able to serialize coderefs since version 2.05.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Storable;
use Data::Dump 'dump';

{
    no warnings;             # Suppress 'used only once' warning
    $Storable::Deparse = 1;  # Needs to be set to true as per docs
    $Storable::Eval    = 1;       # Same as above
}

sub hello_world { print "Hello world!\n" }

my %hash = (
             helloTest => \&hello_world,
             byeTest   => sub { print "Goodbye!\n" },
           );

store \%hash, 'file';            # Could use freeze/thaw for
my $cloned = retrieve( 'file' ); # in-memory serialization

$cloned->{helloTest}();          # Prints 'Hello world!'
```

Comment: Yes, we were experimenting with `Storable` before using `freeze` and `thaw`, but we couldn't get it to actually save the serialized string to disk correctly. Can you provide an example of what it looks like?

Comment: Code looks good, but doesn't seem to work for our situation here. I suspect that the fact the routines are in a separate file is what is causing things to break.

Comment: Storable doesn't handle closures. `++` should be `=1` since `++` is not guaranteed to set to true.

Answer (score 2):

Set [`$Data::Dumper::Deparse`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDumper#Configuration_Variables_or_Methods) to a true value.

This uses [`B::Deparse`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?B%3a%3aDeparse) to reconstruct the source from op codes. This usually, but not always, works.

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -e 'sub foo { print "Hello world" };' \
>     -e  '$Data::Dumper::Deparse=1; print Dumper \&foo'
$VAR1 = sub {
            print 'Hello world';
        };
```

---

If you want to parse a Perl source code file and extract the text of the subroutines, that's a very different problem. But [there's a package for that](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PPI), too:

```
# quick and dirty sub extractor
use PPI;
use Data::Dumper;
$doc = PPI::Document->new( "your_source_code_file_name" );
foreach $sub ( @{$doc->find( 'PPI::Statement::Sub' )} ) {
  @t = $sub->tokens;
  $name = $t[2];
  $code = "sub " . join q//, @t[3..$#t];
  $teh_codez{$name} = $code;
}    
print Data::Dumper::Dumper \%teh_codez;
```

Comment: Somewhat better, I'm getting the following in the file now: `'goodbyeTest' => sub ;,`

Comment: Then maybe the function `runGoodbye` isn't defined or is defined in the wrong package.

Comment: Correct, the functions are actually stored in other files that are then pulled in by a test runner. I could do this by just storing the references separate, but I'm trying to avoid that as this time.

Comment: I have no problem Deparsing subs in other packages. e.g., Deparsing `\&Data::Dumper::Dumper` returns `sub { package Data::Dumper; return 'Data::Dumper'->Dump([@_]); };`

Comment: @ikegami - There in lies the trick though, the package corresponding to the routines aren't actually part of the script. No packages being loaded means that the references apparently point at nothing when I try to dump them to disk.

Comment: @RobZ, So it has nothing with being in another package, but that you're trying to serialise a subroutine that doesn't even exist. Yeah, that's not gonna work, not matter what tool you use. The sub has to exist for it to be serialised.

Comment: @ikegami - That's the conclusion that I've been driving towards for awhile now, downside is that I need to figure out how to to strings into functions names that can be run now instead.

Comment: @Rob Z, Can you paint an animal that doesn't exist? Can you count fruits that don't exist? Can you serialise a sub that doesn't exist?

Comment: @ikegami - Sounds very zen. :)

Comment: @Rob Z, You might want Module::Pluggable if you want to do plugins.

Answer (score 2):

First, Data::Dumper is a debugging tool, not a serialiser. It's not all that good at doing the latter. At the very least, be sure to set the `Purity` option. That'll make it work in some of the case where it wouldn't otherwise work. There are still issues with it breaking aliases, though.

[Storable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Storable) should be used to non-trivial data, and I'd use [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON%3a%3aXS) or a YAML module for trivial data.

Second, what you want can be *attempted* by setting the `Deparse` option.

```
use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

my $serialised;
{
   local $Data::Dumper::Purity  = 1;
   local $Data::Dumper::Deparse = 1;
   $serialised = Dumper($struct);
}
```

It will fail for closures, and XS functions and it doesn't capture pragmas in effect.

```
my $struct = { f => do { my $x = 123; sub { $x } } };
```

produces

```
$VAR1 = {
          'f' => sub {
                     $x;
                 }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you store the hash with the *names* of the subroutines to be called, and then resolve them to subroutine references after retrieval

This code shows the idea

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %testMap = (
  helloTest   => 'runHello',
  goodbyeTest => 'runGoodbye',
);

$testMap{$_} = \&{$testMap{$_}} for keys %testMap;

$testMap{helloTest}();
$testMap{goodbyeTest}();

sub runHello {
  print "runHello\n";
}

sub runGoodbye {
  print "runGoodbye\n";
}
```

Comment: This is the approach that we ended up going with, although I believe that you need `no strict "ref"` in your example for it to work.

Comment: @RobZ:  No it works fine as it is. Try it. `strict 'refs'` doesn't apply to subroutine references so that you can declare a subroutine before it is defined